# How to filter with string comparison?

Tags: sparql

I am trying to extract all the subjects that are alphanumerically greater than (or less than) a literal string.  This didn't work:

```
sparql 
select distinct ?s 
{ ?s ?p ?o. FILTER (?s > "stackoverflow"^^xsd:string). } order by ?s
```

How can I perform string comparison in the `FILTER` clause?

Comment: You have to compare the string values, i.e. `FILTER(STR(?s) > "stackoverflow")`

Comment: despite the brevity, i'd say that's a pretty good answer i'd be happy to upvote and accept

Comment: Ok, but not sure if this really helps. `?s` is an IRI like `http://example.org/a`, so what would be to goal of comparing it to "stackoverflow"? Or did you mean `?o` and are you talking about only `?o` values that are literals?

Comment: I am retrieving all the data from a graph and I segmentize payloads in 1000 triple chunks and then for the next chunk I ask for the next 1000 that are bigger than the last one from the previous chunk, ordered by ?s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`?s` is a subject and subjects in triples are either IRIs or blank nodes.  It's not clear how an IRI should be compared with a string, but in any case, you have to compare the string values, i.e. `FILTER(STR(?s) > "stackoverflow")`